# Can't get list of objects Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[source web code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWVRV.png)

[image]

```
public static void notifications(){

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/header/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/nav/a[3]/div/div/div")));
    WebElement notificationButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/header/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/nav/a[3]/div/div/div"));
    notificationButton.click();

    Array[] posts = (Array[]) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@aria_label='position: relative; min-height: 3681px;']")).toArray();
    System.out.println(posts[0]);
}
```

I tryed this but it's probably bad. I'm trying to get on console all my notifications from Twitter as a text. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use array to hadle your web elements . You can handle list of element as per below with webdrivers:

```
    List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("some/path//a"));
    System.out.println("Size of List: "+myElements.size());
    for(WebElement element : myElements) 
    {        

        System.out.println("elements: "+element .getText());
    }
```

Comment: My question in how can I know which part web source should I get xpath?

Comment: You can form your xpath from DOM structure(extreme right corner) . Also you can use extentions based on your browser